# Background Color Wont Display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure why background-color tag isn't applying to my body element. The only thing i cant think of is i have it covered up with something else but i cant seem to figure out what is wrong. Either way i'm only trying to change the background color to grey. Im still learning and this is only my second project on freecodecamp.

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
header{
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #555
}
#headerText{
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
#headerText2{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#headerImg{
  padding: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
}
#headerImg img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
hr {
 border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
 text-align: center;
}
hr:after {
 content: '§';
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 top: -14px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background: #aaa;
 color: #8c8b8b;
 font-size: 18px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#section2{
  background-color:white;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #555
}
#section3{
  background-color:white;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #555
}

#top-bar-img{
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#top-bar{
  background-color: purple;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #555;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="top-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <img src="http://qlip.in/images/qlip.png" id="top-bar-img"></img>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <header id="section1">
          <div class="row vertical-align">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8" id="center">
              <h3 id="headerText">Nulla interdum convallis turpis, vitae dignissim neque posuere at. Proin sit amet dui pretium, facilisis diam rhoncus, luctus lacus. Etiam nec nibh lorem. </h3>
              <hr></hr>
              <h4 id="headerText2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet - Consectetur adipiscing elit - Morbi faucibus tellus diam</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="headerImg" class="col-xs-3">
              <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/23371317?v=3" class=" img-circle"><img>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div id="section2">
          gfgf
        </div>
        <div id="section3">
          gfgf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `background-color: grey!important;`

Comment: jsfiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/b7Ljjuw3/

Answer (score 5):

You're using Bootstrap and their CSS rules are overriding yours. Make your rules more specific:

```
html > body{
  background-color: grey;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```css
html > body{
  background-color: grey;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
header{
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #555
}
#headerText{
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
#headerText2{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#headerImg{
  padding: 20px 30px 0px 0px;
}
#headerImg img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
hr {
 border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
 text-align: center;
}
hr:after {
 content: '§';
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 top: -14px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background: #aaa;
 color: #8c8b8b;
 font-size: 18px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#section2{
  background-color:white;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #555
}
#section3{
  background-color:white;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #555
}

#top-bar-img{
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#top-bar{
  background-color: purple;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #555;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="top-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <img src="http://qlip.in/images/qlip.png" id="top-bar-img"></img>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <header id="section1">
          <div class="row vertical-align">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8" id="center">
              <h3 id="headerText">Nulla interdum convallis turpis, vitae dignissim neque posuere at. Proin sit amet dui pretium, facilisis diam rhoncus, luctus lacus. Etiam nec nibh lorem. </h3>
              <hr></hr>
              <h4 id="headerText2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet - Consectetur adipiscing elit - Morbi faucibus tellus diam</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="headerImg" class="col-xs-3">
              <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/23371317?v=3" class=" img-circle"><img>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div id="section2">
          gfgf
        </div>
        <div id="section3">
          gfgf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Learn more about CSS specificity at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Note: You should also avoid `!important` at all costs.

Comment: Another option is to include your css file after bootstraps css file

Comment: @NooBskie That doesn't guarantee that your rules will win. Bootstrap's could still be more specific.

Comment: @j08691 It does not guarantee that your rules will win, but then, would you recommend making more complex selectors instead of identifying the specificity and override by cascade? The person asking the question could be lead to precede his selectors with `html`, which in my opinion is not ideal either.

Comment: @Ricky I don't understand what you mean by "would you recommend making more complex selectors instead of identifying the specificity and override by cascade"

Comment: @j08691 Why use `html > body` when Bootstrap only uses `body` in the selector. Referencing the custom css file after Bootstrap and using only `body` seems like a better option to me, that's what I'm wondering.

Comment: @Ricky They're both viable but it depends on the restrictions the OP may have. Maybe they can't load their CSS after Bootstrap. Maybe they'll encounter another conflict with Bootstrap where loading afterwards won't work because of specificity.

Comment: @j08691 Well, the person asking the question does not specify any of that, we can only guess. Just like avoiding `!important` I would avoid using more specific rules when not needed, it can turn into chaos.

Answer (score -1):

You should try adding `!important` to the end of the background-color line. This overrides bootstrap's native background color.

Comment: Generally this is not recommended. It may seem like an easy fix to the problem now, but it leaves you nowhere to go if you run into further specificity issues down the track. See this document for more about specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity